# Is this column view for answers viable in a Survey type format?

Tags: usability-testing, user-centered-design, surveys, question-answer

I have a query about a question type that I'm working on for a survey design. What I wanted to figure out was whether this type of question (see image below) was valid or not in terms of UX. How hard is it for a user to understand this kind of format and what could be a better way to show this information?

[image]

Here we have an example of the question type where we want a user to rate his workspace lighting at office and at home by selecting one of the options. When you select an option it lights up. Once you're done selecting options from both columns (as shown below) you will then automatically be proceeded to the next question.

[image]

Can I please get some advice or mentorship on whether this approach works or should it be done differently?

I would really appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that I see with your approach is that users might select just one option.

I would divide this answer in 2 to guide the user.
When the user clicks the answer in the first part the accordion will collapse the first section (Office) and expand the second section (Home).

[image: Collapsible example]

Comment: I think you make a valid point on this. I will definitely try this approach. It is clearer in establishing that the user needs to answer for both office and home. Thank you!